# Silverlight MediaElement does not work during pageload

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

I cant make the MediaElement object to work in page load. It works fine if I call

```
// the reason is during Page_load MyMediaElement.AudioStreamCount is 0
MyMediaElement.Stop();
MyMediaElement.Play();
```

in a button event. I checked my page_load but nothing seems to be preventing this. Is it because of some threading issue?

Even if I call it on Page_Loaded, it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `MediaElement` to start playing as soon as possible, you can either set its [AutoPlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.autoplay%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to true or try calling the `Play` method within the [MediaOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaopened%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event.

Comment: does MediaOpened means that the MediaLoaded ?

Comment: Yes, it will load the media file, ensure that its valid, and it'll read the headers. At this point, the `MediaOpened` event is fired and the media will is ready to play.